# How to on Multisite manage users over 1 site

Tags: 8, users, multi-sites

My client need 13 Pages with different domains, so we decided to make different DBs with same codebase. Now, he want to manage the users (admin, editors) over 1 site, so he can select which user has access to which site.

We tested CAS which works so far but i'm not able to define which user has access to which site.

How can I do that?

Comment: Sounds like you should have used Domain Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LDAP](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap), you should define in an external directory (openldap, AD or whatever) which website a user can access or not and define rules inside each website (mapping rôles/sites/ldap properties, more infos [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/lightweight-directory-access-protocol-ldap/ldap-authorization-use-cases)).
From there, you can add SSO like [CAS](https://www.drupal.org/project/cas).